# Custom Dialog Box not displaying properly

Tags: java, android, dialog

So I have designed a custom dialog box, and have added some code to try to make it work properly, but in the app the layout gets all skewed and removes some elements of the box. Here are some screenshots of the design vs. what it looks like in the app:

**Design:**

[image: Design]

**In the App:**

[image: In the App]

This is the `.xml` I have for my design

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorBackground2"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialogTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="Game Setup"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/wagerText"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="$0.00"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wagerInput"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dialogTitle"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="165dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="165dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="154dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="154dp"
    android:text="Wager"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bestofText"
    android:layout_width="77dp"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dialogTitle"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="163dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="163dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="139dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="139dp"
    android:text="Best Of"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dialogTitle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/option1"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bestofText"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="81dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="81dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="268dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="268dp"
    android:background="@drawable/my_button_bg"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/option5"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bestofText"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="202dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="202dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="147dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="147dp"
    android:background="@drawable/my_button_bg"
    android:text="5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/option7"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bestofText"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="265dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="265dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="84dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="84dp"
    android:background="@drawable/my_button_bg"
    android:text="7" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/option3"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bestofText"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="142dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="142dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="207dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="207dp"
    android:background="@drawable/my_button_bg"
    android:text="3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/declineButton"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/option3"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:background="@color/colorLightTan"
    android:text="DECLINE" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/acceptButton"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/option3"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/dialogTitle"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/dialogTitle"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="85dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="85dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@color/colorCoral"
    android:text="ACCEPT" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the **code**, I have added to the app to make it appear when you click a button:

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(FlipCoinLobby.this);

View DialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialogbox, null);
final Dialog d = new Dialog(FlipCoinLobby.this);
d.setContentView(DialogView);
d.show();
```

I have looked at some other similar issues, but none of the solutions seem to work for my particular problem. Any help?

Comment: The reason that this happens is you are using fixed size for all views so in smaller device views gets overlapped each other.

Comment: @nik so instead of using `dp` sizes, how can I make everything appear on different sized screens so it is relatively similar throughout all screens?

Comment: well for ex. in option buttons layout instead of fixed size you can use weight in side linear layout and apply same weight for all children so they'll have  same space and give fixed size to linear layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.enter_quantity_dialog);
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: short and simple